# What is happening to my poor Pine tree?

Tags: dryness, pines

My pine tree seems to be drying very fast. It looked much better a week ago, much greener. It had, let's say 10%, of the needles as brown and I thought it might be just the average amount of ones to dry and fall off. It looks like this now:

[image: Pine tree]

What am I to do? Is it dying or is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pines drop a relatively large number of needles each year; because the majority of those yellowing on your tree are not at the tips of the branches, yours looks pretty normal for October in the Northern Hemisphere. I do see that some complete branch tips have yellowed, which may indicate issues with moisture during the end of the growing season. If you haven't had any rain - or not much rain - recently, give it an inch of water out to about three feet from the trunk just to make sure that more branch tips don't yellow.

The tree would greatly benefit from a three-inch layer of wood chips placed around the trunk, with a radius of at least two feet; do not place the wood chips directly against the trunk, though. This will help keep the soil consistently moist during next year's growing season.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! WIll do as you propose with the wood chips to keep it moist. It was a very dry summer here as you have guessed :)